# Scalability of a language

Tags: runtime-performance

When building a language, one of the things to consider is scalability, the ability of a programming language to efficiently manage large or small amounts of code. How should one factor this when making a language?

For example

> C++ is a scalable, object-oriented language, perfect for large, scalable applications thanks to its discrete and direct memory management capabilities and low-level machine functions. [Source](https://www.simplilearn.com/what-is-cpp-programming-article)

Why would some languages need the scalability while others not as much?

Comment: Are you asking about a language or about its compiler? What does "performance" mean for a language?

Comment: What do you mean? I wasn't under the impression these were mutually exclusive

Comment: @PabloH I got the impression it was about interpreted languages

Comment: My bad sorry guys I changed the question @RydwolfPrograms

Comment: We designed and implemented JScript for scenarios where 90% of browser scripts were one line, 99% were under ten lines. Scripts were to make the monkey dance when you moved the mouse. It was a different world in the 1990s. We had no concept that there would be multiple-hundred-thousand-line frameworks running on any given page. It's hard to make predictions, especially about the future.

Answer (score 1):

There are trade-offs between scalability, safety, usability and productivity.

For instance, if you perform bounds checks on every array access, the CPU has to actually do them in worst case scenarios. The code runs faster, if you don't do bounds checks, but it might do complete nonsense or crash.

If you have exceptions in that case and some static reflection, you might be able to produce a nice error message that helps the developer to fix the issue. However, this makes the binary larger and presence of exceptions can prevent optimizations.

If you have reflection and garbage collection, your code and some algorithms can be much simpler and the learning curve is shorter.

Finally, a many software producing employees want to develop code interactively. This is a contradiction to paradigms required to make a compiler generate fast end efficient code. But that's usually fine for them because they don't want or can pay a developer. Think of Excel scripting and all the "No code" stuff.